# Create a [rest] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are over 2000 questions related to using REST with Drupal. It is clearly a subject that many people are interested in and many people have problems with. I think this is a good opportunity for a [rest](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest) tag.

Comment: When you add a tag to a question also try to remove the tag from the question title to remove redundant information. For example when you have a question like "How do I create users via REST?" and you tag it `rest` then edit the title to "How do I create users" (which both is still too broad for a good title, but I think you get the idea).

Comment: I added the [rest] tag to a few issues yesterday as a trial - I'm not about to go off and immediately tag 2000 issues ... What I am finding is that these questions really do need REST in their title, because everything you can do with REST you can do by "normal" means as well. So *most* of the questions are like your example "How do I create users"/"How do I create users with REST".  I don't think removing REST from the title of these is actually helpful, so maybe that indicates that [rest] shouldn't be a tag since these issues can be found by other means?

Comment: Well, I agree with having a rest tag, and then remove the tag from the title.

Comment: Yes, we don't need a tag in the title. The tag itself makes clear the context of a question. Adding the tags in the title isn't helpful at all. Imagine a question title like *8 Views Nodes Entities How do I achieve this?* and imagine a site where all the question titles are like that.